# Very strange shadow glitches on mesh

Tags: modeling

[image][image]

I have a very odd lighting glitch on my ship hull mesh. Does anyone know why this is occurring. Topology is good, normals are facing outward, and there are no double vertices. I’m using Blender 2.8.

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I added download to post. Thanks.

Comment: yes, weird, the normals are strangely oriented

Comment: Yeah I never had this issue on any of my meshes in the old Blender. Is there any way to fix the normals?

Comment: If you export it as an .obj then import this .obj it looks like it fixes the problem, it doesn't explain what was the problem though  ;)

Comment: Wow thank you! It did work!